# How to compute $1+4+7+...+10^{2015}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

How do you compute $1+4+7+...+10^{2015}$? I know that I can use an arithmetic sequence by using the sequence $x_1:=1$ and $x_n=1+3(n-1)$ for $n\geq2$. Now I need to compute $S_n:=\sum_{k=1}^n x_k)$ Can someone help me do this computation?

Comment: This is a simple [arithmetic progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression).

Comment: if $x_n = 10^{2015} = 1+3(n-1)$, then what does n equal?

Comment: Is this a question from an on-going contest?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint.** $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

If you add the first and the last term, you'll get $10^{2015}+1$. The same for the second and the one before the last one. And so on. 
We have $\displaystyle\frac{10^{2015}-1}3\ +1$ numbers. (For the pattern note that for e.g. $1,4$ we have $(4-1)/3\ +1$ numbers.) So, the result is
$$\left(\frac{10^{2015}-1}3+1\right)\,/\,2\,\cdot(10^{2015}+1)\,.$$